How to apply debug property to zipfile extraction process?
Currently I use to following code to zip my files:
def zipdir(path, ziph):
    # ziph is zipfile handle
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            if not file.endswith('.pyc') and '.metadata' not in root and '.Trash' not in root:
                ziph.write(os.path.join(root, file))
    
zipf = zipfile.ZipFile('/tmp/example.zip', mode='w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
zipdir('/Users/me/Documents/Dev/', zipf)
zipf.setpassword(b'1234')
zipf.close()

I would like to add some info about progress there. The text line displaying the file  being processed currently is OK. I wanted to use debug option of zipfile, but it doesn't work:
with zipfile.ZipFile('/tmp/example.zip', mode='w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zipf:
    zipdir('/Users/me/Documents/Dev/', zipf)
    zipf.debug = 3 
    zipf.setpassword(b'1234')

The following error is returned:
OSError: [Errno 102] Operation not supported on socket: '/Users/me/Documents/Dev/Other/Node/wittr/build/server/offlinefirst.sock'

How can I use debug here?

Please add the full error traceback to your question.
